# ways to ask for the deadline of something

Tags: grammar, word-usage, word-choice

A HR person asked me to prepare some documents and give them to her later, and I was trying to ask for the deadline of the submission I guess. Are the following setences correct or do they sound natural?

1. what is the deadline for when I have/need to give you the documents?
2. what is the latest time/date I have/need to give you the documents?
3. until what time do I need to give you the documents

Also are there any other ways I can say this?

Comment: "What is the deadline for handing in the documents?" "What date/time do you need the documents by?" (3) is not idiomatic.

Comment: **Due** is the English word that establishes a deadline. A *due date* is when something is required to be delivered. When are they **due**? is how you would ask the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @KatBunting has mentioned:

*What is the deadline for handing in the documents?*

You could also say:

*When would you need/want the documents handed in?*

Or:

*When are the documents due?*

Comment: I've never asked for a *deadline*.  Not even once.  It's cumbersome.  *Due* is the most common way to ask for simple deadlines.